# Remote Desktop Revocation error SSL

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, ssl-certificate, windows-server-2012-r2

I have a CA-certificate installed on both a Windows 10 and a Windows Server 10 machine. I have a certificate signed by the CA in use with the help of this: [link](https://serverfault.com/questions/444286/configure-custom-ssl-certificate-for-rdp-on-windows-server-2012-in-remote-admini).

When I now connect from my Windows 10 machine to my Windows Server 10, I get the "A revocation check could not be performed for the certificate." error. However, if I click on `View certificate...`->`Certification Path` it says: "This certificate is OK." And also shows the correct link to the CA certificate.

So what is it now? Is my certificate ok, Or did I miss something?

P.S.: All certificates were created using `makecert.exe`, I have several `Subject`s in this certificate, is this a problem for remote desktop?

**Edit 1:** It seems that Remote desktop requires a CRL. ([In this discussion](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/2e64461c-8c20-4e2a-b654-9eb4101ea9c3/rdp-with-custom-certificate-in-windows-7-no-tsconfigmsc-or-group-policy-setting?forum=w7itprosecurity) Ladislav Havlat mentions this).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was indeed the `.crl` file that was missing.

Here is a [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647171.aspx#Step2) that shows how one can create one and how it is installed on the client. If you know how `makecert.exe` runs, here is the command in short quoted from the above [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647171.aspx#Step2):

```
makecert -crl -n "CN=RootCATest" -r -sv RootCATest.pvk RootCATest.crl
```